# mathjax + vue not rerendering equations

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, mathjax

I'm building a vue application and I want to use [MathJax](https://www.mathjax.org/) to render equations. I can get the equations to render when the component is mounted
but I can't get the equations to rerender at a later point.

I made a [code sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/302wznyyp6) to demonstrate this. Try to change the latex equation in the input and nothing changes even though the console shows the watcher is running.

Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong?

I added mathjax via cdn in the head of index.html with the following config

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [['$','$'],['\\(','\\)']],
    }
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_CHTML"></script>
```

and here is the code in my app component

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input v-model="latex"/><br>
    <div>{{latex}}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      latex: '$$\\frac{a}{b}$$'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    reRender() {
      if(window.MathJax) {
        console.log('rendering mathjax');
        window.MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", window.MathJax.Hub], () => console.log('done'));
      }
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.reRender();
  },
  watch: {
    latex: function() {
      console.log('data changed')
      this.reRender();
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am able to make it work by adding 2 things.

https://codesandbox.io/s/x2mlq38m4z

1. add `key` to the div. `key` is an indicator for virtual DOM. When `key` is the same, Vue may reuse the same div element. When `key` change, Vue will render a completely new DOM element, which is helpful when you want to apply 3rd party library's code (MathJax) to the DOM from scratch.

   `<div :key="latex">{{latex}}</div>`
2. use [$nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) so that the rerender happens after the DOM have updated.

like this

```
  watch: {
    latex: function() {
      console.log('data changed');
      this.$nextTick().then(()=>{
        this.reRender();
      });
    }
  }
```